# what are the different type of files (File type) that we can create in java?

Tags: java, file

Like we can create `.txt` (text file), `.csv` (comma separated values file).

What are other file types that we can create using java.

Comment: why do you assume there is a limitation on this?

Comment: You can create any file you want. The only constraint is that the content of the file matches the format that the file extension is associated with.

Comment: You can create any kind of file that you like

Comment: why does this have so many downvotes? It's a valid question. 90% of I/O tutorials use .txt as an example. I was wondering the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java (and in any other programming language able to create files) you can create any kind of file.

There are libraries to create and manage at least:

- pdf - for example [pdfbox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/)
- xls xlsx - [Apache poi](https://poi.apache.org/)
- doc docx - [Apache poi](https://poi.apache.org/)
- txt csv
- json - [Faster jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)
- xml
- yaml
- zip
- jpg gif tif

and all most used formats.

But you can create your format human readable (like txt) or binary (like xls).

Virtually there is no limit on that.